# What is the simplest way to print a counter after a loop has finished?

Tags: javascript

If I run the following code it will output `0`.

```js
var total = 0;
for(var i = i; i <= 100; i++) {
    total = total + i;
}
console.log(total);
```

This is because the line `console.log(total)` doesn't wait for the loop to finish; it just immediately executes.

How can I print the final value of total?

Comment: `for(let i=0;i <= 100; i++) {`

Comment: `i` is undefined, it should be `i=1`. I vote to close as a typo.

Comment: it should be i=1

Comment: JavaScript sure has its share of problems but an implicitly *async* for-loop ain’t one of them ;)

Answer (score 4):

There is a mistake in your code:

change:

```
for(var i = i; i <= 100; i++)
```

To:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
```

And it works:

```js
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    total = total + i;
}
console.log(total);
```

Comment: Questions with typos should be closed.

Comment: Yes, there is a typo but there is also a misconception of why the output is and the answer is here to avoid that.

Comment: The misunderstanding is *directly* related to the undetected typo.

Answer (score 3):

Change *for loop* to

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) { //i=0 instead of i = i
```

`i = i` will cause `i = undefined` and that will cause `i < 100` to fail

Comment: Really? With such reputation, you should know that such questions should be closed, not answered to.

Comment: My answer tells OP why total is `0` because it never enter the loop. Even if it is a typo, is it not worth explaining the output?

Comment: @trincot I totaly agree with gurvinder372: It's worth explaining the output

Comment: I also agree with good gurvinder372 and @Faly. BTW, this should be the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: The output could be explained in a comment, as the OP's misunderstanding is *directly* related to the undetected typo. This should have been closed without answer. It is not a useful question for anyone else than the OP.

Comment: @trincot  *It is not a useful question for anyone else than the OP* - On this I agree, however, that can be said about most questions which gets **less than 3 votes** or are not worded in a way that can be searched. No disrespect - I just don't feel that every problem that can be solved with changing 1 or 2 characters is a typo problem.

Comment: I agree that that is not the hallmark of a typo. But in my opinion in this case it is one.